# Xamarin.iOS app will not build to device but does build to simulator; Realm issue?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, realm

I get the following build error when targeting an iOS device:

> MTOUCH : error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'System.Void* System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe::AsPointer(!!0&)', referenced from the method 'T Realms.MarshaledVector`1::MarshalElement(System.Int32)' in 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Specifically I think the reference is made here: `T Realms.MarshaledVector`

This builds fine on the simulator but it fails when targeting the device. The Realm NuGet Package is installed. In fact I just removed it and re-installed it to see if that might fix it; it didn't.

Anyone know anything else to try to make this run or what could cause this build error only when the target is a device?

```
iOS version: 11.2.1 (15C153)
OSX version: 10.13.2
Visual Studio Community Version: 7.3.2 (build 12)
Xcode: 9.2 (9C40b)
```

... later ...

Ok it appears like it's definitely realm.  Even the act of doing this:

```
using Realms;
var settingsFilename = "/some/path/settings.realm";
var Config = new RealmConfiguration(settingsFilename);
```

Causes Visual Studio Community to fail to build the project with the error mentioned above. I have this code in my AppDelegate `FinishedLaunching`.

Next up I'm gonna try and strip everything away in there and see what happens I guess.

... later ...

Ok the reference error is different now at least.

> MTOUCH : error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'System.Void* System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe::AsPointer(!!0&)', referenced from the method 'T Realms.MarshaledVector`1::MarshalElement(System.Int32)' in 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>           Error processing method: 'T Realms.MarshaledVector`1::MarshalElement(System.Int32)' in assembly: 'Realm.dll'
>           Failed to resolve System.Void* System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe::AsPointer(!!0&)

It specifically calls out: `in assembly: 'Realm.dll'`

Answer (score 0):

So at least for now what I did, after this ate my entire day leaving me with 0 progress. I started a new project, installed the same dependencies

> - Realm (2.1.0)
> - Serilog (2.6.0)
> - Serilog.Sinks.Xamarin (0.1.29)
> - System.Reactive (3.1.1)
> - Xam.Plugin.Connectivity (3.0.3)
> - Xamarin.Auth (1.5.0.3)

No Error.

So I went back to my customer's project, deleted all the packages from `packages.config` and re-installed them all. It doesn't seem to have this build error any longer (*Can't resolve the reference 'System.Void* ...*).

It occasionally seems to fail to deploy to the device properly under debug scenarios with the following error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib

But cleaning the project and trying again, seems to fix it. Also I can turn off *Incremental Builds* under:

`Project Settings -> Build -> iOS Build -> Enable Incremental Builds`

And that will also get past he dyld loading issue.

Per this other questions, [Visual Studio Community missing developer tools for iOS 11.2.1, cannot debug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47915083/1060314), a commenter also recommends just unloading the project from the solution and reloading it to solve the problem as well.

So I'm going to count my blessing and just keep going until it blows up again. I should note this did happen AFTER I upgraded Visual Studio Community in the middle of this project to: *7.3.2 (build 12)*. Again, it only seemed to happen when trying to debug on a device, in this case an iPhone X running *iOS 11.2.1 (15C153)*. I have yet to try on other devices/os versions yet, since again, this literally consumed my whole day yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Same error with Realm 2.0.0.

How i fixed it :

- Installed the NuGet package `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`
- Removed the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` lib in project
  references
- Re-add the lib manually by selecting the file `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll` located in packages folder
  project. (the one installed in step 1)

Hope it'll help !