# Visual Studio Community missing developer tools for iOS 11.2.1, cannot debug

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am tryign to build and run under the Debug profile.

So my Xcode is up to date `9.2 (9C40b)`. Checked the app store and the developer portal, no updates to it. Visual Studio Community is also up to date at `7.3.2 (build 12) (stable channel)`

Connecting my iPhone with only Xcode Running does not update anything as I have seen between other version updates.

Visual Studio Community outputs the following info.

> Connected to: Dev iPhone
>
> error MT1108: Could not find developer tools for this 11.2.1 (15C153) device. Please ensure you are using a compatible Xcode version and then connect this device to Xcode to install the development support files.

Is anyone else running into this? If so, how have you addressed it?

... later ...

The plot thickens. So I rebooted the phone, now I get this error on app startup:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib
>
> required code signature missing.

Per this bug:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=26404

If I disable Incremental Builds on the iOS project, the afore mentioned error is no more.

...later still ...

Clearing Derived Data

```
cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData && rm -rf *
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

And cleaning the project seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Issue solved or still same?

Comment: I think all that did the trick. I could not mark it as the answer yet.

Comment: just try unload the project and reload it.... that's also trick...

Comment: Had the same problem.  I followed instructions just as you wrote and it worked.

Comment: Another note: I had the same issue but for 11.2.2, rebooting the phone and restarting visual studio seemed to make it work again.